# row-major 3-D array address

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have this 3-D array declaration: `A[10..29][2..6][-1..0].`

Assuming this row-major array is stored starting at base address 100, where is element A[25][4][-1] stored? 
 my answer is 416

next question is :
Using the same assumptions, what element is stored at address 2000?

How can i solve such a question?

Comment: What kind of declaration is this? `10..29, 2..6, -1..0`? Am I missing something?

Comment: This is the full question:

Consider the following 3-D array declaration: A[10..29][2..6][-1..0].

    #List the first 10 elements of the array assuming it is stored in row-major order.
    #Do the same for column-major

    #Assuming each array element is size 20, what is the size of the overall array? You don’t have to give the answer if you give me the correct equation.

    #Assuming this row-major array is stored starting at base address 100, where is element A[25][4][-1] stored?

    #Using the same assumptions, what element is stored at address 2000?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help.  I have put it in a code block so that it lines up well.

```
/*
 *  Assuming that the array is laid out row/column/other then...
 *      Row-major           Column-major
 *      A[10][2][-1]        A[10][2][-1]
 *      A[10][2][0]         A[10][2][0]
 *      A[10][3][-1]        A[11][2][-1]
 *      A[10][3][0]         A[11][2][0]
 *      A[10][4][-1]        A[12][2][-1]
 *      A[10][4][0]         A[12][2][0]
 *      A[10][5][-1]        A[13][2][-1]
 *      A[10][5][0]         A[13][2][0]
 *      A[10][6][-1]        A[14][2][-1]
 *      A[10][6][0]         A[14][2][0]
 *
 *  Since the array is 20 rows (29 - 10 + 1) by 5 columns (6 - 2 + 1) by
 *  2 other (0 - (-1) + 1), with each elelment given as size 20, the 
 *  overall array size is 20 * 5 * 2 * 20 = 4000.
 *
 *  The address of element A[25][4][-1], given the array is row-major
 *  begining at 100 is...
 *  Base address                                                          100
 *  Offset index0 = (25 - 10) * ((6 - 2 + 1) * (0 - (-1) + 1)) * 20 =   3,000
 *  Offset index1 =                 (4 - 2) * ((0 - (-1) + 1)) * 20 =      80
 *  Offset index2 =                                (-1 - (-1)) * 20 =       0
 *  Offset for A[25][4][-1]                                         =   3,180
 *
 *  Now that you have the idea, I will leave it to you to determine what element
 *  is at address 2000.  Here is a hint, repeat the above but using substraction.
 */
```